# Obtaining Errors on a code for loading and displaying a DICOM image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, dicom

There was individual, whom post a code to load and display a DICOM image in C# with the ClearCanvas Library. However, I tried t run the code and i'm receiving an error and have a missing library dll component. I would like to know where the individual obtained the library dll file ClearCanvas.Dicom.ImageViewwer.StudyManagement. I've been unable to locate that file on the internet. The code is displayed after the errors. I am grateful thanks.

Usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ClearCanvas.Common;
using ClearCanvas.Dicom;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using ClearCanvas.ImageViewer;
using ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.StudyManagement;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
```

This is the body:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "DICOM Files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (ofd.FileName.Length > 0)
            {

                var imagen = new DicomFile(ofd.FileName);

                LocalSopDataSource DatosImagen = new LocalSopDataSource(ofd.FileName);

                ImageSop imageSop = new ImageSop(DatosImagen);

                IPresentationImage imagen_a_mostrar = PresentationImageFactory.Create(imageSop.Frames[1]);

                int width = imageSop.Frames[1].Columns;

                int height = imageSop.Frames[1].Rows;

                Bitmap bmp = imagen_a_mostrar.DrawToBitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

                imageOpened = true;

            }
            ofd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you download the assemblies from https://github.com/ClearCanvas ?  Did you add them as references in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to referencing the proper assemblies ([here](https://github.com/ClearCanvas)... it's linked from the main page of clearcanvas.ca) I mentioned in a comment, consider employing the `using` keyword since `OpenFileDialog` implements `IDisposable` like so:

```
using(OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
   ofd.Filter = "DICOM Files(*.*)|*.*";
   if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // rest of your code goes here
   }
}
```

This has the benefit of calling `ofd.Dispose()`  *automatically*, even if the code inside the `using` block throws an exception. This works for anything that implements `IDisposable` (so bitmaps, fonts, streams, etc.)

Comment: I have one last question, the studymanagement files I have seen, they are not in dll format, they are in a C file. How do I add the studuManagement to the library format displayed in your code. Is there a conversion method. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ClearCanvas library. I'm assuming that StudyManagement namespace is likely already part of the assembly you added as a reference. If not, then you can either build it yourself or consider contacting ClearCanvas directly and asking for support.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the code actually..

These are the DLLs I used in my project:

Clearcanvas:

```
ClearCanvas.Common.dll
ClearCanvas.Desktop.dll
ClearCanvas.Dicom.dll
ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Common.dll
ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.dll
ClearCanvas.Utilities.Manifest.dll
```

Others I also added since I was getting an error when trying to show the image..

```
log4net.dll
nunit.framework.dll
WindowsBase.dll
BilinearInterpolation.dll --> For this one make sure you add either the 32 or 64 bits dll depending on what's your project defaults.
```

Comment: Mr. Matimont, how and where did you download the

Comment: Hello Mr. Matimont, how and where did you download the using ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.StudyManagement;ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Common.dll ClearCanvas.Utilities.Manifest.dll and log4net.dll. It has been tedious trying to locate these files. if you have any idea, will you let me know. thanks

Comment: If you downloaded Clearcanvas from GitHub, you shoud have a directory lije this:
GitHub_Original\GitHub\ClearCanvas\Desktop\Applets\WebBrowser\bin\Debug
You should see these: 
ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Common.dll
ClearCanvas.Utilities.Manifest.dll
log4net.dll

Comment: I found ClearCanvas.Utilities.Manifest.dll log4net.dll. But not ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Common.dll  and the study management file that I found, is only in cs file format, any idea how to convert to dll library file. Thanks

Comment: When you import the DLLs, you then can use this statement:

    using ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.StudyManagement......


ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Common.dll is in multiple locations within the Clearcanvas project, one of these is:
GitHub\ClearCanvas\Desktop\Applets\WebBrowser\bin\Debug

Comment: Mr. Matimont, I thank you, but I downloaded ClearCanvas SDK 2.0 and ClearCanvas reference library on the main ClairCanvas.ca site. I'm stll unable to find these dll file StudyManagement and ClearCanvas.ImageViewer.Common. Are you able to somehow post these dll for me to download. I will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: what you need to do is build the clearcanvas solution, then you will see the DLLs. I think you haven't done that yet. Open Visual Studio, then build the clearcanvas solution...